# Use stat_summary to bootstrap confidence interval for proportion stats

Tags: r, ggplot2, proportions

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance!

**The Background:**

I created a plot with x on the x axis and the proportion of responses on the y axis.
I used the following code:

```
# create example data:

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:20),
                  x = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
                  group = rep(1:2, 20))
               

# create plot:
df1 |>
ggplot(aes(x = x, colour = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = after_stat(prop)), stat = "count") +
  geom_line(aes(y = after_stat(prop)), stat = "count")
```

**The Problem:**

Now, I want to bootstrap the confidence interval for each proportion point and plot it with an errorbar/pointrange geom. How is that possible?

**My attemps to solve the issue:**

1. attempt:
   I tried the `stat_summary` geom using `mean_cl_boot` (something like `stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar")`. However, it did not work as the function missed the y in `aes()` (error: `stat_summary() requires the following missing aesthetics: y`). Thus, I have no idea how to tell `stat_summary` to calculate bootstraped proportions.
2. attempt:
   I computed the bootstraped proportion with a function I built and added the confidence interval point by point using `geom_annotate`. That works in principal but is awfull lot of work.

I would realy appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could try the geom "pointrange", it includes all of the aesthetics, i.e. y, ymin and ymax.